# Render radio button form from a collectionType [Symfony]

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a quiz for my application with Symfony.
At this point I have 3 class, Qcm, QcmQuestion and QcmAnswer.
I have multiple questions which contains multiple answers, and I want to display answers as radio button.

I only achieve to display them as input. How can I display them as radio button ?

**BaseController.php**

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()>getRepository('QcmBundle:QcmQuestion');
    $qcmQuestions = $em->findBy(array('qcm' => $id));
            $formBuilderQuestionnaire = $this->createFormBuilder();
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($qcmQuestions as $qcmQuestion) {
                $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($i, FormType::class, $qcmQuestion);
                $formBuilder
                    ->add('question')
                    ->add('qcmAnswers', CollectionType::class, [
                        'entry_type' => QcmAnswerType::class
                    ])
   ;
                $formBuilderQuestionnaire->add($formBuilder);
                $i++;
            }
            $form = $formBuilderQuestionnaire->getForm();
            $form->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Envoyer',
                "attr" => array("class" => "btn btn-primary")));
            return $this->render('QcmBundle:qcm:qcmQuestions.html.twig', ["qcmQuestions" => $qcmQuestions, "form" => $form->createView()]);
```

**QcmAnswerType**

```
class QcmAnswerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('response');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'QcmBundle\Entity\QcmAnswer'
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'qcmbundle_qcmanswer';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved my problems, I used EntityType with a query inside it.

```
Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?"
```

I had this error because I needed to pass to `createNamedBuilder` the entire array of questions like this :

```
 $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($i, FormType::class, $qcmQuestions);
```

The final result :

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('QcmBundle:QcmQuestion');
        $qcmQuestions = $em->findBy(array('qcm' => $id));
        $formBuilderQuestionnaire = $this->createFormBuilder();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($qcmQuestions as $qcmQuestion) {
            /* @var $qcmQuestion QcmQuestion */
            $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($i, FormType::class, $qcmQuestions);
            $formBuilder
                ->add('qcmAnswers', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'QcmBundle\Entity\QcmAnswer',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'label' => $qcmQuestion->getQuestion(),
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($qcmQuestion) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('qcmAnswer')
                            ->join('qcmAnswer.qcmQuestion', 'qcmQuestion')
                            ->where('qcmAnswer.qcmQuestion = :qcmQuestionId')
                            ->setParameter('qcmQuestionId', $qcmQuestion->getId());
                    },
                ]);
            $formBuilderQuestionnaire->add($formBuilder);
            $i++;
        }
        $form = $formBuilderQuestionnaire->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want `CollectionType` + `QcmAnswerType` but you want just `EntityType` with options `multiple: false` and `expanded: true`.

So instead of

```
   ->add('qcmAnswers', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => QcmAnswerType::class
    ])
```

try with something like:

```
   ->add('qcmAnswers', EntityType::class, [
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
    ])
```

More info about EnttiyType can be found in [Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons).

Comment: I tried this earlier but I ended up with this error and I haven't been able to solve it "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?"

Comment: If you're not using entities, but not managed objects, then use `ChoiceType` instead.